# filter nested array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to filter hasPermission state is false to remove that object:

this is my array of objects:

```
const videos = [
    {
        name: ' name',
        url: '1',
        hasPermission: true,
        tags: [
            {
                tag: 'reels',
                hasPermission: true
            },
            {
                tag: 'reels2',
                hasPermission: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: ' name2',
        url: '2',
        hasPermission: false,
        tags: [
            {
                tag: 'demos',
                hasPermission: true
            },
            {
                tag: 'demos',
                hasPermission: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'video name3',
        url: '2',
        hasPermission: false
    }
];
```

the expected output is :

```
{
        name: ' name',
        url: '1',
        hasPermission: true,
        tags: [
            {
                tag: 'reels',
                hasPermission: true
            }
        ]
    }
```

first I want to check the main object hasPermission state if it's false remove that object . incase the main object hasPermission state is true check children object of tag if tags object hasPermission is false remove those objects only.

Comment: so ignore the tags? you just want a filter mang. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using filter and map.

First we filter out the main object:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Then we map over the result and modify the tags with another filter and object destructuring.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```
const filtered_videos = videos.filter(item => item.hasPermission).map(item => {
    return {
        ...item,
        tags: item.tags ? item.tags.filter(tag => tag.hasPermission) : [],
    }
})
```